# Usage of "because of" on interrogatives

Tags: questions

Which one is more grammatical than other sentences?
Which one sounds better than others?

> **1.—** Because of what do you do it?
>   **2.—** Of what do you do it because?
>   **3.—** What do you do it because of?

Comment: None of them is idiomatic: *Why do you do it?*

Comment: None of them work for me, they all sound bad. Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps a context may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do you do it? Or Why are you doing it?

These are the questions you are trying to ask. You are trying to use the structures of your language. But "because of" isn't used as a question word in English. That's why none of your sentences is correct.

Answer (score 2):

None of your sentences are grammatically correct, and it's difficult to figure out what you are trying to ask:

> **Because of** what do you do it?
>   Of what do you do it **because**?
>   What do you do it **because of**?

maybe you are trying to ask:

> **Why** are you doing *something*?
>   **What** has caused you to do what you do?

**Because** is usually used to introduce an answer, it is not used to introduce a question.

> A: **Why** *did something happen*?
>   B: **Because** *of this reason*.

Possible ways of using **because** in a question are:

> Is it **because** it was raining that you got wet?
>   **Because** it was raining, is that why you got wet?